# I am being spammed

Tags: support, feature-request

One of [my answers](https://serverfault.com/a/398192/9517) has become the target for a spam bot. Twice today, once yesterday and several more times in the recent past an Anonymous user has [suggested an edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/177200) which is basically a set of spam links.

Can I disable Edit Suggestion notifications for this one Answer? 
Can the post be locked so that new edits are disallowed ?

Feature Request:

Can SE send EMP pulses back to any IP address that tries to edit this answer ?

Seriously though there really is no need to edit that answer - automatically banning any IP address that tries to edit it would be a great win.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer has been locked. Note that this also prevents *you* from editing it, so feel free to hunt down a moderator if you need to do so.

As for the spammers, check back in 6 to 8 weeks...