# Nuke accounts or ban addresses that edit my honeypot answer

Tags: feature-request

I've [previously written](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7914/i-am-being-spammed) about being edit spammed by a link spammer. A kind-hearted mod ;) took pity on me and locked the question. The lock has expired and now I'm being [spammed again](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/186313).

Please nuke any account that touches that answer or block the IP address.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any accounts associated with the IP addresses which have bee proposing edits to your answer. So there's no one to ban. The good news is they're getting their IP addresses rate-limited and blocked rapidly all on their own.

That said, I've changed the lock on this answer to a permanent lock. Not sure why it was only set to 1 week, as the problem would just start up again after that.

Comment: I didn't lock it permanently because that prevents voting, and I think the answer should have more upvotes... but that doesn't seem like it's going to happen, and since the spammers keep targeting this answer for some reason, I suppose the permanent lock is the better course of action.

Answer (score 3):

Love to oblige, but they seem to just be proposing edits as an anonymous user.  So, I relocked it for a week.

Comment: In that case the IP address could be banned.

Comment: @Iain unfortunately, the guy's not dumb enough to use the same IP twice, at least as far as I've seen. :/